# ANR on Broadcast of FCM message

Tags: android, firebase

I'm getting this App Not Responding error:

> ANR on Broadcast of Intent  {
>   act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x11000010
>   pkg=com.addcn.android.house591
>   cmp=com.addcn.android.house591/com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver
>   (has extras) } com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver

Looks like there is some issue with firebase with android?

Comment: Plese provide more details.

Comment: If you think there is a problem with Firebase SDKs, please contact Firebase support directly.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: I am also receiving same kind of issues after 13sept19.and mostly above android 8.1 --- Logs: https://pastebin.com/t7vaUQaG

Answer (score 0):

Updating to com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.2 or later should fix the issue. If it doesn't, please contact support.